# Apex Mocks github deployment to Production stuck in Status: Queued

Tags: apexmock, financialforce

I'm attracted to the FinancialForce apexmocks and related libraries, and have successfully deployed to Trailhead playgrounds, Dev sandboxes and our full sandboxes.  The deployments ran quite smoothly and quickly.  When I went to deploy apexmocks to our Production instance, the status doesn't move past Status: Queued.  Are there settings that I should check in Production to see why there's such a difference?

I will try again in the wee hours, but I tried yesterday afternoon, (relatively) early this morning and ~2:00 p.m. EST, and I see neither progress nor errors.

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: The tool does not run tests during the deployment, so will not deploy into production orgs, I may add a checkbox with a big disclaimer around it if there is demand. Bottom line this is a developer tool.

via the man himself: https://andyinthecloud.com/2013/09/24/deploy-direct-from-github-to-salesforce/

Comment: What *would happen* if one were to attempt a Production deployment..?  The statuses could have changed from Status: Queued to Status: InProgress, as an example, but if tests are not running, it won't finish successfully, at any rate.  Is the GitHub Salesforce Deploy Tool going to keep trying for .. a very long time?  ... ever?

Comment: yes; because this is an unmanaged package - it effectively becomes part of your development code base and as such, should be deployed through your normal devops pipeline;  +1 for using apexmocks; be aware of this [handy resource](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/252460/my-apexmocks-arent-working-what-could-be-wrong) if also using apex-common