# Apex Mocks test error for Domain class

Tags: contentdocumentlink, fflib, apexmock

We have been using FFLIB(Apex commons) in our org.I have been trying to write a test case for a Content Document Link (Salesforce Files)Domain layer But i have been getting the error : "System.NullPointerException: Argument cannot be null."
I am new to the library and now that i have tried few things , i am assuming it is something to do with ContentDocumentLink.
Can somebody please help me resolve this.I want to adopt the AEP and Apex mocks and not go back to writing usual test cases.

My class:

```
public class XYZ_DOM_ContentDocumentLinks extends fflib_SObjectDomain implements XYZ_DOM_IContentDocumentLinks{
    

    public static XYZ_DOM_IContentDocumentLinks  newInstance(List<SObject> sObjectList) {
        return (XYZ_DOM_IContentDocumentLinks) XYZ_Application.Domain.newInstance(sObjectList);
    }

    
    public Map<Id, String> getBodyAsStringByLinkedEntityId (){
        Map <Id, String> bodyAsString = new Map<Id, String>();
        for(ContentDocumentLink file : (List<ContentDocumentLink>) Records){
            Blob FileBody = file.ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersion.VersionData;
            String attachmentAsString = FileBody.toString();
            bodyAsString.put(file.LinkedEntityId, attachmentAsString);
        }
        return bodyAsString;
    }

public XXYZ_DOM_ContentDocumentLinks(List<SObject> records) {
        super(records);
    }

    public class Constructor implements fflib_SObjectDomain.IConstructable {
        public fflib_SObjectDomain construct(List<SObject> records) {
            return new XXYZ_DOM_ContentDocumentLinks(records);
        }
    }

}
```

My Test Class:

```
// Given
        ContentDocumentLink record = new ContentDocumentLink(
            Id = fflib_IDGenerator.generate(ContentDocumentLink.SObjectType)
            );
    
    List<ContentDocumentLink> testContentDocumentLinkRecords = new List<ContentDocumentLink> { record };
 

    // When
    XYZ_DOM_IContentDocumentLinks contentDocumentLinks = XYZ_DOM_ContentDocumentLinks.newInstance(testContentDocumentLinkRecords);

        contentDocumentLinks.getBodyAsStringByLinkedEntityId();

    // Then
        System.assertEquals(1, contentDocumentLinks.getBodyAsStringByLinkedEntityId().size());
```

It's line 13 which is erroring out :
Class.XYZ_DOM_ContentDocumentLinks.getBodyAsStringByLinkedEntityId: line 13. This belongs to the Domain class:
`String attachmentAsString = FileBody.toString();`

**Stack Trace:**
-- | --

Class | XYZ_DOM_ContentDocumentLinks_Test

Method Name | testGetBodyAsStringByLinkedEntityId

Pass/Fail | Fail

Error Message | System.NullPointerException: Argument cannot be null.

Stack Trace |

Class.XYZ_DOM_ContentDocumentLinks.getBodyAsStringByLinkedEntityId: line 13, column1

Class.IRR_DOM_ContentDocumentLinks_Test.testGetBodyAsStringByLinkedEntityId: line 33, column 1

Comment: Have you identified the line on which the NPE happens? The call stack should show which line in your code suffers this exception even if it is thrown from within a call you make to the fflib.

Comment: @PhilW Yes, its line 13 Class.XYZ_DOM_ContentDocumentLinks.getBodyAsStringByLinkedEntityId: line 13, column 1...Which is this from the class:
```
            String attachmentAsString = FileBody.toString();

```

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to add the necessary details so it is nice and clear?

Comment: if you are trying to use apexmocks then you need to use [edit] and show how you are setting up the mock Domain class; see also [Why are my Apex Mocks not working](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/252460/my-apexmocks-arent-working-what-could-be-wrong)

Comment: Thanks @cropredy. I edited to show my entire domain class, if that's what you are asking.I am thinking, it's something to do when I create ContentDocumentLink record but there is no content/versiondata , but I am unable to understand how to create a wholesome record with mocks.

Comment: your test class is not using apexmocks at all (at least in the snippet you provided). Your test class is invoking the real domain class. If you are trying to test the domain class directly, you don't mock it.  It sounds like you want to mock CDL records in order to verify the `getBodyAsStringByLinkedEntityId` method.  If that is correct, I can give you an answer

Comment: @cropredy Yes, I am trying to test the domain class itself hence no mocking.Domain class requires CDL records in order to  test ```getBodyAsStringByLinkedEntityId``` method which manipulates, converts returns the blob as string.

Comment: See my answer as I anticipated your response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my opinion, the best tool to mock SObjects and their relationships when there are non-writeable fields is the [SObject Fabricator](https://github.com/mattaddy/SObjectFabricator) by @mattaddy on GitHub.

So, this means you will have the following:

```
// given mock CDLs
        
ContentDocumentLink[] mockCDLs = new List<ContentDocumentLink> {
  (ContentDocumentLink) new sfab_FabricatedSObject( ContentDocumentLink.class )
   .set(ContentDocumentLink.Id,fflib_IDGenerator.generate(ContentDocumentLink.SObjectType))
   .set(ContentDocumentLink.LinkedEntityId,fflib_IDGenerator.generate(Opportunity.SObjectType))
   .set('ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersion.Id',fflib_IDGenerator.generate(ContentVersion.SObjectType))
   .toSobject(),
          ... next CDL
}

// workaround for Blobs which don't serialize/deserialize on sobjects properly
mockCDLs[0].ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersion.VersionData = Blob.valueOf( 'abc' ); 


// given domain class

XYZ_DOM_IContentDocumentLinks domain = XYZ_DOM_IContentDocumentLinks.newInstance(mockCDLs);

//  when getBodyAsStringByLinkedEntityId

Map<Id,String> results = domain.getBodyAsStringByLinkedEntityId();

// Then verify
...
```

Be sure your Interface `XYZ_DOM_IContentDocumentLinks` includes an entry for

```
Map<Id,String> getBodyAsStringByLinkedEntityId();
```

Comment: So you mean there is no way to 'mock' CDL records with fflib, so either i have to go 'DML' way or use 'SObject Fabricator '? If yes,which is the preferable way?I am a novice hence little apprehensive of using so many third party libs in org and create dependencies.

Comment: There is an sobject mocking class in fflib but I find it clunky to use when dealing with relationships and collections of mocked objects.  My org is a heavy fflib org and adding sfab was a nice complement.  You only need to use sfab when mocking objects with unwriteable fields.  Of course, you can also use Json.serialize/deserialize from strings and maps of strings.  Others may suggest that approach as their answer.  Sfab uses Json.serialize/deserialize under the covers but I find the expressive power of the builder pattern handy.

Comment: This is the error that I am getting: ```Error Message System.JSONException: Cannot deserialize instance of <unknown> from VALUE_STRING value YWJj or request may be missing a required field ```.I also changed Blob.valueOf('abc') instead of instanceOf.InstanceOf is throwing error : ```Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void newInstance(String) from the type Blob```

Comment: Whatever I try,it just says ```System.JSONException: Cannot deserialize instance of <unknown> from VALUE_STRING```:(

Comment: ah - my approach doesn't work because Blobs won't pass through the sfab `JSON.deserialize(JSON.serialize(...))` mechanism. I'll have to think about this

Comment: A bug on SObject Fabricator has been raised: https://github.com/mattaddy/SObjectFabricator/issues/16, and a solution is hopefully in the pipeline.  A temporary workaround is to build the SObject without the VersionData set (but another field on LatestPublishedVersion set instead - e.g. LastModifiedDate'), and then setting the blob after the SObject is generated.  A complete example of the workaround exists in the bug report linked above.

Comment: updated my answer thanks to @RobBaillie workaround

Comment: Thanks for all the help.Appreciate it

Comment: Note that SObject Fabricator has now been fixed and the workaround is no longer required.