# Partial mocking using ApexMocks Framework

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, fflib, apexmock

I want to perform partial mocking using the Salesforce FFLib ApexMocks framework. For example, I have a class like the one below:

```
public class PropertiesServiceImpl implements IPropertiesService {
public void autoArchiveLeads(List<Property__c> properties) {
    List<Lead__c> leadsToBeArchived = getLeadsToBeArchived(properties);
    // ...business logic
}

public List<Lead__c> getLeadsToBeArchived(List<Property__c> properties) {
    // ...business logic
    return leadsToBeArchived;
}}
```

When I'm writing unit test for the **autoArchiveLeads** method, I want mocked **getLeadsToBeArchived** method to be executed. Something similar to the following:

```
mocks.when(serviceMock.getLeadsToBeArchived(mockedProperties)).thenReturn(mockedLeads);
```

How can I achieve this using the ApexMocks framework? My test class looks like the following:

```
@IsTest
public with sharing class PropertiesServiceTest {
@IsTest
static void itShouldArchiveTheLead() {
    // ...stubbing operations and mocking data.
    Test.startTest();
    new PropertiesServiceImpl().autoArchiveLeads(properties);
    Test.stopTest();
}}
```

Can you provide me with guidance on how to achieve this?

**UPDATE 2023-08-12**

The issue is that these two methods are located within the same class, and as you can see below, if I call the method through PropertiesService (reinitializing the PropertiesServiceImpl class), I can achieve the desired result:

```
public void autoArchiveLeads(List<Property__c> properties) {
    List<Lead__c> leadsToBeArchived = PropertiesService.getLeadsToBeArchived(properties);
    //...business logic
}
```

And the test method is like the following:

```
 static void itShouldArchiveTheLead(){
    //populating leads and properties lists.
    fflib_ApexMocks mocks = new fflib_ApexMocks();
    fflib_ISObjectUnitOfWork unitOfWorkMock = new fflib_SObjectMocks.SObjectUnitOfWork(mocks);
    IPropertiesService propertiesServiceMock = (IPropertiesService)mocks.mock(PropertiesServiceImplEs.class);
    mocks.startStubbing();
    mocks.when(propertiesServiceMock.getLeadsToBeArchived(properties)).thenReturn(leads);
    mocks.stopStubbing();
    Application.UnitOfWork.setMock(unitOfWorkMock);
    Application.ServiceByDivisionCode.setMockByKey(IPropertiesService.class,mockPropertiesService,'es');
    Test.startTest();
       new PropertiesServiceImplEs().autoArchiveLeads(properties);
    Test.stopTest();}
```

PropertiesService class is like the following:

```
public with sharing class PropertiesService {
private static IPropertiesService service(String divisionCode) {
    return (IPropertiesService)  Application.ServiceByDivisionCode.newInstanceByDivisionCode(IPropertiesService.class, divisionCode);
}
public static void autoArchiveLeads(List<Property__c> properties) {
    //Some mappings to determine which records belong to which division code.
    service(divisionCode).autoArchiveLeads(properties);
}

public static List<Lead__c> getLeadsToBeArchived(List<Property__c> properties) {
    //Some mappings to determine which records belong to which division code.
    return service(divisionCode).getLeadsToBeArchived(properties);
}}
```

However, I do not believe that calling a method located within the same class through the PropertiesService is the correct way. My issue is similar to what was mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39198848/mock-methods-in-same-class) stackoverflow thread. That thread is related to Java Mockito framework but the problem is the same and I want to achieve the same solution using ApexMocks.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE!. Please see [ask] on getting the most from the community.

Happy to help here but what have you tried so far? There are several resources on apexmocks that you can find on the apexmocks gitHub repo as well as this [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/252460/my-apexmocks-arent-working-what-could-be-wrong)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the heads up, I should have given more details. I updated the thread and also added a link to a thread that experienced a similar problem. That thread is actually related to the Java Mockito framework, but the problem is the same.

Comment: If you mock the service and that service has two methods and both get called in the unit test, then both methods need to be stubbed

Comment: I apologize for the delayed response. In my unit test, my aim is to cover the autoArchiveLeads method. However, this method calls the getLeadsToBeArchived method within the same class. Mocking the PropertiesServiceImpl class would cause the real implementation of the autoArchiveLeads method not to execute and prevent me from obtaining the coverage for it. My aim is to test the real implementation of autoArchiveLeads while having the getLeadsToBeArchived method return the fake result I set. The challenge arises from both methods being in the same class. I might be misinterpreting something.

Comment: So I'm not sure if stubbing both of these methods would help me achieve coverage for the autoArchiveLeads method.

Comment: so the way to do this would be to code a new mock Class that _extends_ `PropertiesServiceImpl` where `getLeadsToBeArchived` has a mock implementation and you let the mock subclass execute `super.autoarchiveLeads`.  Then inject this mock class

Comment: Thank you very much, that's a good idea. I wish there would be a simpler way.